# Definition of instantiation and specialization are both dependant on each other

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

In the standard, [temp.spec]/4 sentence 2 states:

> A specialization is a class, function, or class member that  is either instantiated or explicitly specialized.

However, [temp.inst]/1 sentence 1 states:

> Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program.

So a specialization is a class/function/member that is instantiated, but it won't be instantiated until a specialization is referenced? Somebody please explain this to me.

Answer (score 1):

1. explicitly instantiated → done, also becomes a specialization
2. explicitly specialized → done, so you get a specialization
3. otherwise

   · specialization is referenced in context that requires complete type
   · but specialization is not known yet
   · then:
   → the compiler will try to instantiate it for you.
   → doing so has the effect of creating the specialization you referenced.

Definition kind of loops over itself. It just says if you name it without having explicitly asked for it, compiler will be clever about it and do it for you instead of complaining.

Basically it's the rule that allows us to use templates without having to explicitly instantiate for all types we will use.

---

Baking comment into answer:

- A template can be thought of as a recipe with blanks. Eg: "T pie".
- A specialization is the recipe with some blanks (partial specialization) or all blanks (full specialization) filled
- Referencing a specialization is just naming it. For instance, by saying out loud "apple pie", I refer to the apple specialization of my T pie recipe.
- Instantiating is actually cooking the pie.

To cook the pie, I must put the actual ingredients, so cooking the apple pie also makes the "apple pie" concept exist.

The implicit instantiation part means that you don't need to explicitly tell the compiler "with that T pie recipe, you can make apple pies, pear pies, leek pies, …". The moment you ask it for an apple pie, it knows what you mean and cooks a pie<apple>.

Comment: How would the specialization not be known? For example, assume Bar is a class template taking one type parameter. With `Bar<int>` b;` the specialization is `Bar<int>`, how is the specialization not known?

Comment: It gets instantiated when the compiler sees `Bar<int>` for the first time in a context where it needs to know the complete type. Until that point, it just doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't understand how you can reference a specialization that is not know. What does that mean?

Comment: Does referencing a specialization (ex: `Bar<int>;`) not require the specialization to exist?

Comment: No indeed, referencing a specialization that does not yet exist makes the compiler generate it. Thus “implicit”.

Comment: So when we reference a specialization, that specialization will only be instantiated if it is in the proper context. However, the definition states that a specialization IS instantiated. Would this be correct then? 
`Bar<int>; // references a specialization, but is not a specialization as it is not yet instantiated` 

`Bar<int> b; // references a specialization, and the specialization is instantiated, so this is a specialization`

Comment: The what does "A specialization is a class, function, or class member that is either instantiated or explicitly specialized." mean? It says that the specialization needs to be instantiated?

Comment: It says "instantiating has the effect of specializing" (item 1 and 3 in answer) and "explicitly specializing also has the effect of specializing" (item 2 at the top of the answer).

Comment: So referencing a specialization creates an instantiation, and therefore also a specialization

Comment: Yes! Assuming that referencing is done in appropriate context. *(btw I'm deleting some of my comments since I moved the content to the answer)*.

Comment: In your answer, when you refer to full specializations, this also includes specializations that are generated purely by the compiler, correct? (Ex: `template<typename T> struct Bar {}; Bar<int> b; // references a specialization in proper context, causing it to be implicitly instantiated, creating the specialization`

Comment: Yes, instantiation implies full specialization. You cannot cook something without knowing which ingredients you put.